# How to fix this round-off error?

Tags: c++, floating-point, numerical-stability

Apologies for the long code.  This is as far as I could reduce it.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QWidget>
#include <QtGui/QImage>
#include <QtGui/QPainter>

#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class View : public QWidget {

  typedef pair<double, double> Point;

  unsigned char* _buffer;
  double centerx, centery, scale;
  double xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;
  double xprec, yprec;
  double xratio, yratio;
  double fwidth, fheight;
  double xlen, ylen;
  int width;
  int height;

public:
  View(int w, int h) : width(w), height(h) {

    _buffer = new unsigned char[4 * w * h];

    fwidth = static_cast<double>(width);
    fheight = static_cast<double>(height);
    double aspectRatio = fwidth / fheight;

    centerx = 0;
    centery = 0;
    scale = 2.3;
    xlen = aspectRatio * scale;
    ylen = 1.0 * scale;

    xmin = -(xlen * 0.5) + centerx;
    xmax = -xmin;
    ymin = -(ylen * 0.5) + centery;
    ymax = -ymin;

    xprec = xlen / fwidth;
    yprec = ylen / fheight;
    xratio = fwidth / scale / aspectRatio;
    yratio = fheight / scale;
  }

  double roundX(double x) { return std::floor(x / xprec) * xprec; }
  double roundY(double y) { return std::floor(y / yprec) * yprec; }

protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    render();
    painter.drawImage(
      QPoint(0, 0),
      QImage(_buffer, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB32));
  }

private:
  void render() {
    memset(_buffer, 0, 4 * width * height);
    for (double i = xmin; i < xmax; i += xprec) {
      for (double j = ymin; j < ymax; j += yprec) {
        Point p(roundX(i), roundY(j));
        int x = static_cast<int>((p.first * xratio) - (xmin * xratio) );
        int y = static_cast<int>((p.second * yratio) - (ymin * yratio) );
        _buffer[4 * (x * width + y)    ] = 255;
        _buffer[4 * (x * width + y) + 1] = 255;
        _buffer[4 * (x * width + y) + 2] = 255;
      }
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  View view(512, 512);
  view.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

The code, instead of producing a white window, produces a white window with lines which are the result of round-off error.  I think the source of the problem are `roundX()` and `roundY()` functions, but I'm not sure.  I also don't know how to fix this.  Any ideas?

Comment: There's rounding happening in a few places.  Your `for` loops stick out as *accumulated* rounding.  Given that `View` is constructed with ints and the pixel locations are ints, I would recommend retooling that logic so floating point values are not used for intermediate values.

Comment: I'd recommend using `sizeof(variable)*width*height` instead of `4*width*height` throughout the program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Qt and I prefer C. So, below is a C program that imitates your `render()` in `render1()` and has a corrected implementation in `render2()`.

The main problem of your `render()` is that it uses prematurely rounded values from `Point p(roundX(i), roundY(j));`. If you use unrounded `i` and `j`, things will improve dramatically, but you're still going to suffer from the rounding errors of your additions, multiplications and so on.

But those rounding errors aren't large and they don't accumulate to a large error in the end. So, the final correction is the addition of `.5` prior to conversion to the integers `x` and `y`. Without it, the floating point value can be slightly less than the nearest integer that you want to get and when you convert this `double` into `int`, you get a value that is one less.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

double centerx, centery, scale;
double xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;
double xprec, yprec;
double xratio, yratio;
double fwidth, fheight;
double xlen, ylen;
int width;
int height;

void InitView(int w, int h)
{
  double aspectRatio;

  width = w; height = h;
  // _buffer = new unsigned char[4 * w * h];

  fwidth = width;
  fheight = height;
  aspectRatio = fwidth / fheight;

  centerx = 0;
  centery = 0;
  scale = 2.3;
  xlen = aspectRatio * scale;
  ylen = 1.0 * scale;

  xmin = -(xlen * 0.5) + centerx;
  xmax = -xmin;
  ymin = -(ylen * 0.5) + centery;
  ymax = -ymin;

  xprec = xlen / fwidth;
  yprec = ylen / fheight;
  xratio = fwidth / scale / aspectRatio;
  yratio = fheight / scale;
}

double roundX(double x) { return floor(x / xprec) * xprec; }
double roundY(double y) { return floor(y / yprec) * yprec; }

void render1(void)
{
  double i, j;
  int cnt;
  char usedx[1 + 512 + 1];
  char usedy[1 + 512 + 1];

  printf("render1():\n");
  memset(usedx, 0, sizeof usedx);
  memset(usedy, 0, sizeof usedy);

  printf("x's:\n");
  for (cnt = 0, i = xmin; i < xmax; i += xprec)
  {
    int x = ((roundX(i) * xratio) - (xmin * xratio));
    printf("%d ", x);
    cnt++;
    usedx[1 + x] = 1;
  }
  printf("\ncount: %d\n", cnt);
  for (cnt = 1; cnt <= 512; cnt++)
    if (!usedx[cnt])
      printf("missing x: %d\n", cnt - 1);

  printf("y's:\n");
  for (cnt = 0, j = ymin; j < ymax; j += yprec)
  {
    int y = ((roundY(j) * yratio) - (ymin * yratio));
    printf("%d ", y);
    cnt++;
    usedy[1 + y] = 1;
  }
  printf("\ncount: %d\n", cnt);
  for (cnt = 1; cnt <= 512; cnt++)
    if (!usedy[cnt])
      printf("missing y: %d\n", cnt - 1);
}

void render2(void)
{
  double i, j;
  int cnt;
  char usedx[1 + 512 + 1];
  char usedy[1 + 512 + 1];

  printf("render2():\n");
  memset(usedx, 0, sizeof usedx);
  memset(usedy, 0, sizeof usedy);

  printf("x's:\n");
  for (cnt = 0, i = xmin; i < xmax; i += xprec)
  {
    int x = ((i * xratio) - (xmin * xratio) + .5);
    printf("%d ", x);
    cnt++;
    usedx[1 + x] = 1;
  }
  printf("\ncount: %d\n", cnt);
  for (cnt = 1; cnt <= 512; cnt++)
    if (!usedx[cnt])
      printf("missing x: %d\n", cnt - 1);

  printf("y's:\n");
  for (cnt = 0, j = ymin; j < ymax; j += yprec)
  {
    int y = ((j * yratio) - (ymin * yratio) + .5);
    printf("%d ", y);
    cnt++;
    usedy[1 + y] = 1;
  }
  printf("\ncount: %d\n", cnt);
  for (cnt = 1; cnt <= 512; cnt++)
    if (!usedy[cnt])
      printf("missing y: %d\n", cnt - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
  InitView(512, 512);
  render1();
  render2();
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/JNJTYX)):

```
render1():
x's:
0 0 0 2 2 4 5 5 7 7 9 10 10 12 12 14 15 15 17 17 19 20 20 22 22 24 25 25 27 27 29 30 30 32 32 33 35 36 36 37 38 40 41 41 42 43 45 46 46 47 48 50 51 51 52 54 55 56 56 57 59 60 61 61 62 64 65 66 66 67 69 70 71 71 72 74 75 76 76 77 79 80 81 81 82 84 85 86 86 87 89 90 91 91 92 94 95 95 96 97 99 100 100 101 103 104 105 105 106 108 109 110 110 111 113 114 115 115 116 118 119 120 120 121 123 124 125 125 126 128 129 130 130 131 133 134 135 135 136 138 139 140 140 141 143 144 145 146 146 148 148 150 151 152 153 153 155 156 157 158 158 160 162 163 163 165 166 167 168 168 170 171 172 173 174 175 175 177 178 179 180 180 182 183 184 185 185 187 188 189 190 190 192 193 194 195 195 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 371 373 374 375 376 376 378 379 380 381 381 383 384 385 386 386 388 389 390 391 391 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 420 422 423 424 425 425 427 428 429 430 430 432 433 434 435 435 437 438 439 440 440 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 479 481 482 482 484 484 486 487 487 489 489 491 492 492 494 495 496 497 497 499 500 501 502 502 504 505 506 507 507 509 510 511 
count: 512
missing x: 1
missing x: 3
missing x: 6
missing x: 8
missing x: 11
missing x: 13
missing x: 16
missing x: 18
missing x: 21
missing x: 23
missing x: 26
missing x: 28
missing x: 31
missing x: 34
missing x: 39
missing x: 44
missing x: 49
missing x: 53
missing x: 58
missing x: 63
missing x: 68
missing x: 73
missing x: 78
missing x: 83
missing x: 88
missing x: 93
missing x: 98
missing x: 102
missing x: 107
missing x: 112
missing x: 117
missing x: 122
missing x: 127
missing x: 132
missing x: 137
missing x: 142
missing x: 147
missing x: 149
missing x: 154
missing x: 159
missing x: 161
missing x: 164
missing x: 169
missing x: 176
missing x: 181
missing x: 186
missing x: 191
missing x: 196
missing x: 372
missing x: 377
missing x: 382
missing x: 387
missing x: 392
missing x: 421
missing x: 426
missing x: 431
missing x: 436
missing x: 441
missing x: 480
missing x: 483
missing x: 485
missing x: 488
missing x: 490
missing x: 493
missing x: 498
missing x: 503
missing x: 508
y's:
0 0 0 2 2 4 5 5 7 7 9 10 10 12 12 14 15 15 17 17 19 20 20 22 22 24 25 25 27 27 29 30 30 32 32 33 35 36 36 37 38 40 41 41 42 43 45 46 46 47 48 50 51 51 52 54 55 56 56 57 59 60 61 61 62 64 65 66 66 67 69 70 71 71 72 74 75 76 76 77 79 80 81 81 82 84 85 86 86 87 89 90 91 91 92 94 95 95 96 97 99 100 100 101 103 104 105 105 106 108 109 110 110 111 113 114 115 115 116 118 119 120 120 121 123 124 125 125 126 128 129 130 130 131 133 134 135 135 136 138 139 140 140 141 143 144 145 146 146 148 148 150 151 152 153 153 155 156 157 158 158 160 162 163 163 165 166 167 168 168 170 171 172 173 174 175 175 177 178 179 180 180 182 183 184 185 185 187 188 189 190 190 192 193 194 195 195 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 371 373 374 375 376 376 378 379 380 381 381 383 384 385 386 386 388 389 390 391 391 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 420 422 423 424 425 425 427 428 429 430 430 432 433 434 435 435 437 438 439 440 440 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 479 481 482 482 484 484 486 487 487 489 489 491 492 492 494 495 496 497 497 499 500 501 502 502 504 505 506 507 507 509 510 511 
count: 512
missing y: 1
missing y: 3
missing y: 6
missing y: 8
missing y: 11
missing y: 13
missing y: 16
missing y: 18
missing y: 21
missing y: 23
missing y: 26
missing y: 28
missing y: 31
missing y: 34
missing y: 39
missing y: 44
missing y: 49
missing y: 53
missing y: 58
missing y: 63
missing y: 68
missing y: 73
missing y: 78
missing y: 83
missing y: 88
missing y: 93
missing y: 98
missing y: 102
missing y: 107
missing y: 112
missing y: 117
missing y: 122
missing y: 127
missing y: 132
missing y: 137
missing y: 142
missing y: 147
missing y: 149
missing y: 154
missing y: 159
missing y: 161
missing y: 164
missing y: 169
missing y: 176
missing y: 181
missing y: 186
missing y: 191
missing y: 196
missing y: 372
missing y: 377
missing y: 382
missing y: 387
missing y: 392
missing y: 421
missing y: 426
missing y: 431
missing y: 436
missing y: 441
missing y: 480
missing y: 483
missing y: 485
missing y: 488
missing y: 490
missing y: 493
missing y: 498
missing y: 503
missing y: 508
render2():
x's:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 
count: 512
y's:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 
count: 512
```